# Sed script to find certain lines and replace words

Tags: sed, substitution

I need to write a sed script that, 
on all lines starting with “/*” and ending with “*/”, any occurrence of “perl” to “PERL”.
Can I use an if statement?

if(line starts with /* & ends with */)
replace perl with PERL

Here was my prompt

Write a single sed script which will do all of the following:

(a) reduce all white space (blanks and tabs) to a single space,

(b) delete all blank lines (no non-blank characters) and

(c) change, on all lines starting with “/” and ending with “/” (* is not meant as a wildcardhere), any occurrence of “perl” to “PERL”

this is what I have so far

s/^[ ]*$/ /g

/^$/d

I finished part a and part b, I have no idea how to do part c

Comment: What have you tried?  `sed` does not have "if" statements. It's not that kind of language.

Comment: `sed '/^\/.*\/$/s/perl/PERL/g'` ?

Comment: Does it really NEED to be sed? Do you want lines that start with `/` or with `/*`? Should `hyperlink` become `hyPERLink`? What exactly do you mean by `I am trying to write this in a script, not on the command line.`? Edit your question to include some concise, testable sample input and expected output and include cases you do NOT want changed, if any.

Comment: It's kind of funny that @ghoti's answer, which beats the current two answers by nearly half an hour, is a better and more portable answer (not dependent on GNU)...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '\#^/.*/$#s/perl/\U&/g' file
```

The first address limits the scope of the following substitution to lines beginning and ending in `/`. The substitution replaces all occurrences of `perl` with `PERL` thoroughout such lines.